# How I can write custom messages?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I tried to find a good ways to create custom error messages in Protractor. And I found just three ways to do this:

1. Use "jasmine-custom-messages".
   But I don't like this syntax: (I think that code looks pretty better if error message writes after expect)

   ```
   since(function(expected) { 
      return 'Number =/=:' + expected +', it == :' + this.actual; })
   .expect(column.get(0)).toEqual("7");
   ```
2. Create custom matchers and make my own messages. I don't like it too, because I have a lot of different situations for one type of matcher. Also, I don't want to rewrite old matchers and increase my code.
3. Use syntax: `expect().toBe().because('my message')` 
   That looks wonderful! But, if I truly understand, I should make corrections in source jasmine code if I want to use this syntax. I think it isn't very good.
   Maybe somebody knows another ways to solve my problem?

Comment: Just a minor thing, but I just noticed when looking through your questions that it applies to all your questions: You should avoid putting a tag (protractor) into the title, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging for some more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a [custom message as an extra argument to your matcher](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/641#issuecomment-54736801):

```
expect(column.get(0)).toEqual("7", "This is not something I've expected");
```

Which would produce the following output:

```
Expected something to equal 7, "This is not something I've expected".
```

Comment: And for clicks: `button.click().then(function(){
            return true;
        }, function(err){
            console.log('Could not click button ' + err);
        });`